# class name as variable in python

Tags: python, oop, types, argument-passing

I remember the following code in C++:

```
myObj = MyClass();
typedef typeof(myObj) NewClass;
NewClass   newObj = NewClass();
```

Then `myObj` and `newObj`  are from kind of MyClass.

Now I need to write a `function` in `python` and  pass `myobject` to my `function`, then new call my `constructor` of `myobject`. I have many `class`.

**Question:** How i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates a reference to MyClass:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> myObj = MyClass()
>>> NewClass = myObj.__class__
>>> newObj = NewClass()
>>> myObj, newObj
(<__main__.MyClass object at 0x102740d90>, <__main__.MyClass object at 0x102740d50>)
```

This creates a new class based on myObj's class:

```
>>> myObj = MyClass()
>>> NewClass = type("NewClass", (myObj.__class__,), {})
>>> newObj = NewClass()
>>> myObj, newObj
(<__main__.MyClass object at 0x102740d90>, <__main__.NewClass object at 0x102752610>)
>>>
```